# Como posso saber se a conexão ao banco de dados foi bem sucedida?

Tags: c#, conexão

eu preciso de uma ajuda. Comecei a programar em c# agora e queria fazer uma espécie de status para o meu programa. Algo do tipo "Conexão ao banco de dados: Conectado.". 
Eu fiz a conexão e meu programa já coloca tudo o que eu preciso no meu banco no MySQL, mas o meu usuario não vai ter acesso ao banco quando usar o programa entao queria um jeito de mostrar que está tudo funcionando. Como posso fazer um return para que eu mude a propridade text da label?
Estou no caminho certo? Não vou colocar código aqui porque eu realmente não faço a minima de como fazer isso. Pesquisei bastante mas não achei, se alguem já abriu uma pergunta parecida, por favor me mandem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não especificou o que está usando pra se conectar ao MySQL. Normalmente, é utilizado o `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`, mas também é possível fazer com driver ODBC (`System.Data.Odbc`).

Em ambos os casos, a classe de conexão herda a classe abstrata `DbConnection` que possuí o atributo `ConnectionState State { get; }` que serve para verificar o status da conexão.

Exemplo:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection({connection string})
//ou 
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection({connection string});

if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    //Está tudo ok
}
else
{
   //Não está conectado

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Tutorial.SqlConn;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConnectMySQL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting Connection ...");
            MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Openning Connection ...");

                conn.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Connection successful!");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

}
```